Beginning of a dark energy (cosmological constant) dominated universe
Consider a flat universe with only dark energy (cosmological constant)
In such universe, the Friedmann Equation can be written as:
$$H(t)^2 = \left(\frac{\dot a}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{8\pi G \varepsilon_\Lambda}{3c^2}$$
By integration it shows that:
$$a(t) = \exp\left(H_0(t-t_0)\right)$$
In the beginning of the universe, $a = 0$, this can only achieved when $t \rightarrow -\infty$. Thus this universe has no start (the condition cannot be achieved)
But everything must have a start, so how did this universe start in the first place, does it have a big bang like our universe, or it just forms from void and become a universe?

No offense, but the phrase "everything must have a start" is a bit problematic. Where does a circle start? Where do infinitely long lines start? On a more physical level I am having a bit of a problem with the definition of time (and space) in a universe that does not contain matter. Clocks and rulers are, whether we like it or not, massive devices. I do not know how one can define any of the quantities in these equations without matter. It is matter that partitions spacetime so that we can talk about scale in the first place.

What's wrong with it starting the same way our own dark energy dominated universe started? (But I also don't see the problem with not having a beginning.)

@Sten, the problem is our universe is multi component, not a single component universe, so in the beginning of our universe, it is not dark energy dominated and it can have a start.

You have correctly observed that an eternally dark energy dominated universe has no beginning. Another way to see this is to realize that a dark energy dominated universe is a static universe. Its density is constant in time, and its metric can be written in a manifestly static form,
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=-\left(1-\frac{r^2}{H^2}\right)\mathrm{d}t^2+\left(1-\frac{r^2}{H^2}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2\mathrm{d}\Omega^2,$$
where $H$ is the constant Hubble rate (see de Sitter space).
If you want a universe that grows from an initial singularity ($a=0$, infinite density), you need to start in a non-dark-energy-dominated phase.

So you are suggesting that this universe has no beginning at all?
